# Escape sequence for "Delete"

Tags: c++, escaping

I am looking for a way to write the following in a better way

```
else if (c == (wchar_t)(127))
    return true;
```

where '\x7f' represents the ascii character 127, or the delete key.

Is there a C++ escape sequence/#define for this?

eg: \n, \t, \b...

Comment: With most keyboard interfaces the `Del` key doesn't generate ASCII `DEL`.

Comment: `\x7f` is also a escape sequence, you can check it by your own at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: To answer your literal question, "nope".

Comment: @Alf, in this interface.. it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no escape character for delete